# How to fix "fatal error: Carbon/Carbon.h: No such file or directory", when trying to deploy to Heroku - (Django)

Tags: python, django, gcc, heroku

I am attempting to deploy a project I made on to Heroku, but when I try to push the project with:

```
git push heroku master
```

it ends up giving me an error that looks like this:

```
appscript_3x/ext/ae.h:26:10: fatal error: Carbon/Carbon.h: No such file or directory
        #include <Carbon/Carbon.h>
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     compilation terminated.
     error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

       ----------------------------------------
   Command "/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-jq3tilcm/appscript/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-dpw2ji3n-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-jq3tilcm/appscript/
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

I've tried searching around for what to do, but I can't find anyone with the same problem and I don't know where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try reinstalling heroku.

Comment: I tried to reinstall heroku, but that doesn't seem to have changed anything.

Comment: I had the same problem in past but I don't remember how I fixed it .

Comment: Is git installed in your system ?

Comment: Yes, Git is installed on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met the same problem as you when `git push heroku master` my flask project. I'm not sure which package leads to this problem, but it is definitely due to one of over 100 packages.


Because I deployed successfully when I used the original `requirements.txt`. But heroku declined push several times after I ran `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, which added over 100 packages that installed automatically by anaconda. I removed some packages that cannot be found by heroku, and finally, it showed the same error as you met. Then I reset `requirements.txt` to the original version and it worked!


My suggestion is that only adding the packages that you need and you are familiar with. Hope this can help you!

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you very much. I can't tell you what the issue was since I was essentially remove so at random, so to speak (I am very new to all of this), but I was able to deploy it after fixing this, and some other non-related issues. So again, thank you.